# what steps to follow to organize/browse files after PhotoRec has finished

Tags: data-recovery

Can you please recommend to me what steps to follow after PhotoRec has created a bunch of directories like this

```
RECUP_DIR.1
RECUP_DIR.2
RECUP_DIR.3
RECUP_DIR.4
```

Do this folder mean anything of they are just random names ?

For instance I want to have all the pictures (png/jpeg/similar extensions) to be on the same folder all the DOC images on another and so

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1**

Create a file called **MergeByExt.sh**

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ] || ! [ -d "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 DIRECTORY EXTENSION" >&2
  exit 1
fi

folder=$1
ext=$2

mkdir $2
exts=$(find $folder -type f | grep $2)

for f in $exts; do
    mv $f $2
    echo $f moved to $2
done
```

Then you can call it like this (example to merge all the MP3 files in a single folder)

```
MergeByExt.sh /path/to/photorec/recover/root/folder .mp3
```

The folder will be created in the path were you executed the script

---

**SOLUTION 2**

This solution will create a folder with each extension inside each RECUP_DIR.X directory

Like this

```
RECUP_DIR.1\txt
RECUP_DIR.1\png
RECUP_DIR.1\jpg
RECUP_DIR.1\doc
```

Save this text to **ByExtension.sh**

```
dir=$1
if [ "x$dir" != "x" -a -d "$dir" ] ; then
    cd "$dir"
fi

dir=$(pwd)
basedir=$(basename "$dir")

exts=$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | grep '^\./.*\.' | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.][^.]*\)$/\1/' | sort -u)

for e in $exts; do

    # Skip extension if this directory is already named by extension.
    if [ "$basedir" = "$e" ] ; then
        continue
    fi

    mkdir "$e"
    for file in *.$e; do
        mv "$file" "$e"
    done
done
```

The you can go to main folder where PhotoRec folder recover the files and run this command

```
find . -depth -type d -print -exec /path/to/script/ByExtension.sh {} \;
```

Taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575901